# npmjs.com is showing cloudflare error 1034, and npm CLI is showing E403

Tags: npm, cloudflare

I know this is a kinda weird question, but I couldn't find any relevant info about this issue elsewhere so I took the easier way and wrote here.

My problem seems to be related only to my PC, that I cant access npmjs.com, I have no clue why. When I try accessing the npmjs.com website it tells me that Cloudflare errored with error 1034 ( Edge IP Restricted )

[Cloudflare error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB5QP.jpg)

This does not happen when accessing docs.npmjs.com, that works just fine. The other part of the problem is that not even npm CLI is working, when I try to npx or install something it errors with E403 - Forbidden.

[npm CLI E403 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTxl3.jpg)

As I said previously this only happens on my PC, elsewhere on my network this does not happen.
I have a desktop PC connected with a cable to my router, but when I check with my work laptop on wifi, everything is working as it should be.
I tried connecting it straight to the modem, but that does the same so I isolated it to be an issue on my PC only.
This issue has been happening since yesterday when I found out after coming back to node.js after some time.

Just in case it could be related, I'm using a pi-hole with OpenDNS settings ( Had an unused raspberry pi, so I followed tutorial on youtube on how to get it working ).
To this day I haven't had a single problem with it, I've been using it for over a year now.

Thank you for reading and potentially answering my question.